# Job flow/Orchestration

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions, orchestration

I have a spark job which runs on EMR cluster. The job currently generates multiple files in S3 in the end.
However now we want to take those files and do further processing. From a orchestrations standpoint should I use step function for the different step involved, or is it possible to use that same spark job running on EMR cluster to pick up the files after they are written? If the later is possible then I can handle everything in one Spark job and one EMR cluster.
If not possible, could you advise how the Step function would look like? Here is the job flow:

[Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKGW3.png)

I included the current arch that I am thinking. Our flow although ends in 1st EMR job.We want to include the 2nd EMR job just for some additional processing after the 1st Spark job generates the s3 files

Comment: It depends on the type of process that you want to do on these files. From your description it might be sufficient to define a simple Lambda function that will be triggered on each new file in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are writing the output of the first EMR job to S3 because it will be used for something else other than as input to the second job? If so, you can do something like this in a single EMR job:

```
df1=spark_function_implementing_first_job(...)
df2=spark_function_implementing_second_job(df1)
spark.write.parquet("s3://....",df1) # Write out first job output
spark.write.parquet("s3://....",df2) # write out output of the second job
```

This is also more efficient then writing the output of first job to S3 in order to load it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple EMR jobs that you want to run in sequence, Step Functions can orchestrate those for you. Step Functions has an [Optimized Service integration for EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-emr.html) which includes support for the .sync / Run a Job pattern. With this pattern, you can submit a task using `arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync` and Step Functions will submit that and wait for completion before it continues.

In addition, for that second step of processing the files in S3, you might find [the new Distributed Map feature of Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-asl-use-map-state-distributed.html) useful. With this, you can specify the bucket and prefix for where the first job will produce the files. Then Step Functions can execute a sub-workflow for each of them, where you might use Lambda or Fargate or some other service to process the files generated in the previous step.